# Retrieving email from a specific sender using appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

Is there a way to retrieve emails in an email thread from a specific sender using google script?

I want to record the email coming from that specific sender in google Spreadsheet.

Thank you

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Gmail API reference.

On the [Method: users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) you will find the `q` parameter that allows you to filter the messages you get by using the query:

`from:someuser@example.com`